# Angular AutoComplete is returning value as [Object Object]

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

My requirement was to show the selected value in the Input Box and get the Selected Id and Value to the .ts file. As I need the Id and Value I am binding the option value directly to [value]. But if I do that it's getting printed as [Object Object].

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
            <mat-label>Enter Hotel Name</mat-label>
            <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selectedclient($event)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of clients; let i = index" [value]="option">
                    {{ option.name }}
                  </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
            <mat-icon matSuffix>location_on</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Ts File

```
    options = [
        { id: 1, name: 'One'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Two'},
        { id: 3, name: 'Three'}
       ];

selectedclient(event) {
     console.log(event.option.value);
   }
```

Stackblitz Editor URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-n4tvmj

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You want to make use of the [`displayWith`](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) attribute. Per the manual:

> If you want the option's control value (what is saved in the form) to
>   be different than the option's display value (what is displayed in the
>   text field), you'll need to set the `displayWith` property on your
>   autocomplete element. A common use case for this might be if you want
>   to save your data as an object, but display just one of the option's
>   string properties.
>
> To make this work, create a function on your component class that maps
>   the control value to the desired display value. Then bind it to the
>   autocomplete's `displayWith` property.

### Template side

```
<mat-autocomplete ... [displayWith]="getOptionText">
```

### Script side

```
getOptionText(option) {
  return option.name;
}
```

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-cddqia**

Comment: Its working as expected but I am getting this error. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
    at MatAutocomplete.push../src/app/pages/hotels/homepage/homepage.component.ts.HomepageComponent.getOptionText [as displayWith] (homepage.component.ts:49)
    at MatAutocompleteTrigger.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js.MatAutocompleteTrigger._setTriggerValue (autocomplete.es5.js:925)
    at autocomplete.es5.js:628

Comment: @GvsAkhil There must be a case where your option is null, you can check the value within `getOptionText` with something like `return option ? option.name : null;` (replace `null` with anything more appropriate if need be).

Comment: Ya Its working thanks a lot but one doubt we are not passing any parameter in [displayWith]="getOptionText" but its returning the correct name. How is it possible?

Comment: @GvsAkhil This simply holds a reference to a function, Angular will automatically pass whatever you set as `[value]` as its argument.

Comment: Okk thanks a lot I am struggling with it from past one hour

Comment: What if this works on one page and shows `[Object Object]` anyway on another one? Option has been chosen correctly, `[displayWith]="myFunc"` where `myFunc()` does not get called at all.

Comment: The function gets call a LOT even with Angular's OnPush change detection strategy.

Comment: It works with Angular 12, thanks!